# Bounce messages disappearing on G Suite

Tags: civimail, bounce, g-suite

I've noticed that all of our mailings seem to have a 100% delivery rate. This seems incredibly unlikely, so I set up some test contacts with non-existent addresses at a domain I control. I tested e-mailing those addresses from a Hotmail account, and they all responded with bounce messages as expected. But when I sent a mailing to those contacts through CiviCRM it still reports 100% delivery.

I'm using G Suite, so our bounces should be coming to a G Suite address bounces@example.net, but when I log into that mailbox, no bounce messages seem to have been received.

I'm sending with mail(). My SPF config looks correct, including the IP of the CiviCRM server, and mailings do successfully get delivered to valid addresses. I've set up a filter as suggested in the [CiviMail documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/inbound/#using-a-google-suite-account-for-the-return-address). All I can think is that perhaps Google disregard without warning bounce messages that appear to be in response to messages they know their mail system didn't send? Does anyone use this configuration, and know whether that's correct? Or know what else might be going on?

Comment: If your FROM address is a gsuite address then yes it might be like you say and google is rejecting. I'd suggest using smtp instead of mail() and send it thru gmail servers using the credentials for the from address.

Comment: Did you check that bounce messages are not going to the SPAM folder? It happened to us and we fix it adding a filter as described in the documentation.

Comment: @FrancescBassasiBullich Yep, spam folder is empty, and have the filter set up to no avail.

Comment: @Demerit Thanks, if you can replicate and confirm that is what Gmail is doing I'll accept an answer. Now testing SMTP and still having problems, but I guess that's another question!

Comment: 100% delivery rate just means it didn't record any bounces.  Since there is no positive confirmation of delivery in general, you assume a mail was delivered unless you get a bounce.  But of course there's no guarantee you receive the bounce ...